# Formatting a listView in android (My items are to skinny)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

My text in my list view is really skinny. I could just change the text size to make it bigger but I want to check if there is something else I can do so it automatically selects a decent size based on a devices screen size and resolution.

My main activity holds the list view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My listItem xml is how each item in the list view is formatted:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemName" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding padding to the `TextView`.

`android:padding="5dp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proportions along with Paint.measureText():

```
(text size / measureText width) = (perfectSize / screenWidth)
```

Solving for the perfect text size:

```
perfectSize = (text size / measureText width) * screenWidth;
```

You can find the screen width with `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()` from the Display class.

OR

it is always better to set the size of text in sp (Sp is scaled independently with respect to the normal font size of the device. ) or you can use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge`